# How do I package a log4j configuration file in a NetBeans Platorm application?

Tags: configuration, log4j, netbeans-platform

Packaging a log4j configuration file in a NetBeans Platform application apparently requires some thinking through. This is what I tried...

I put log4j.xml in src/main/resources/my/package/log4j.xml of some_netbeans_module. The package is a public module package (i.e. classes from this package are used from other packages). I rebuilt the module and confirmed that the file does, in fact, get packaged into the module.

In my classes I get an instance of the logger the way I always do:

```
static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ThisClass.class);
```

Every NetBeans Platform application has a my_app.conf file which makes it possible to set certain properties. This is where I set log4j.conf:

```
log4j.configuration="/my/package/log4j.xml"
```

Now, when I run the application, I see the following output:

```
[INFO] /home/me/my_app/application/target/my_app/bin/../etc/my_app.conf: 5:
log4j.configuration=/my/package/log4j.xml: not found
```

What is wrong with the above configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `my_app.conf` file if you append the `log4j.configuration` property to the `default_options` property, like so:

```
default_options="...<other options> -J-Dlog4j.configuration=my/package/log4j.xml"
```

then this option will get passed to the JVM.  Notice that the `log4j` property has `-J-D` appended to it.  The `-J` is used by NetBeans to delineate JVM properties and the `-D` is used by the JVM to [delineate a system property](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html#options).

Also you can/should drop the quotes and the initial `/` as the quotes are not necessary and NetBeans will complain if you have the initial `/`

The other way to do this, and the way that I prefer since it doesn't require editing the `.conf` file, is to put the log4j.xml file into the default package. If you have other requirements that prevents you from doing this then remember that you must put the `log4j.configuration` property in the app's platform.properties file while your in dev mode and running the app inside of the IDE.  Like so:

```
run.args.extra=-J-Dlog4j.configuration=my/package/log4j.xml
```

**Edit:** For questions regarding NetBeans Platform you might have better luck posting to the [NetBeans Platform Users](http://forums.netbeans.org/platform-users.html) forum.

Comment: I'll give it a try later today and see where it gets me. I'm not too optimistic, though: I've found samples of my_app.conf files which set the log4j.configuration parameter exactly as I did. I find the approach a bit cleaner, if it works, than adding it as a JVM property in default_options. I definitely appreciate the suggestion!

Comment: Sure thing.  Let us know how it turns out

Comment: I tinkered with it a bit and found out that /my/package works the same as my/package (no starting slash) and that the variables in the conf. file are not system properties but really environment variables, which is why it didn't work before. Thanks. ;)

Comment: You're welcome. Notice the edit as well. Honestly you'll have better luck with these types of questions in the forum.